# Google Cast channel_error

Tags: google-cast

I have a basic sender app that gets a "channel_error" when chrome.cast.SessionRequest() is called.  This only occurs when I am using a custom receiver.  When I use the default receiver I do not have this problem.  I have tried this with the "cast-custom-receiver" example on github, and got the same error.  I have registered my app, paid the $5, and am passing my applicationId when calling SessionRequest().  I can't find any documentation or forum posts that address what might cause the "channel_error" anywhere.

The chrome.cast.Error object that I am getting has the following properties.
code: channel_error, description: cancel, details: null

Anyone have any ideas what might be causing this error?

Answer (score 1):

I got exactly the same issue. Restarting the chrome cast via androids "Chromecast" app solved this issue for me.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Unfortunately this did not help in my situation.